# Copy few selected sub-directory from a directory to another directory in UNIX

Tags: unix, copy

I want to copy a few selected sub-directory from one directory to another directory.

I can use

```
cp -r copyFromDirectory/* copyToDirectoy
```

But it will copy everything from `copyFromDirectory` to `copyToDirectoy`, which I want to avoid since there are more than 100 subdirectories in `copyFromDirectory`.

I can always go for brute force and copy them one-by-one, but I am looking for any one line solution.

Name of subdirectories that I want to copy are two characters long, can this fact be used somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can do the following (provided you can type out all the subDirs):

```
cp -r copyFromDirectory/{subDir1,subDir2,subDir3} copyToDirectoy
```